# Mongoose/mongo many to many with computed field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema. Each user has many posts and each post has list of users who favorited it.

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', {
  name: String,
  posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }]
});

var Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
  name: String,
  favorited: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

I need to select all user posts with a boolean flag is it favorited or not.

I've started with:

```
User.findById('56e14680476f47200f1f598e')
  .populate('posts')
 .then(u => {
  console.log(u);
})
.catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Output:

```
   [ { favorited: [Object],
       __v: 0,
       name: 'post 1',
       _id: 56e14680476f47200f1f5991 },
     { favorited: [],
       __v: 0,
       name: 'post 2',
       _id: 56e14680476f47200f1f5992 },
     { favorited: [],
       __v: 0,
       name: 'post 3',
       _id: 56e14680476f47200f1f5993 } ],
  __v: 0,
  name: 'user 1',
  _id: 56e14680476f47200f1f598e }
```

Aggregation, map-reduce, or maybe re-design schema? Maybe there are good examples of complex structures? Where to dig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one

```
User.findById('56e14680476f47200f1f598e')
    .populate('posts')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            // populate `posts` again
            Post.populate(user.posts, {path:'favorited', model: 'User'}, function(err, ret) {
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                else
                    console.log(require('util').inspect(ret, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
            })
        }
    });
```

---

Second thought, if there are litter fields in `User` collection, you could just nest `user` information into `Post` collection, rather than reference it.

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
  name: String,
  favorited: [{ name: String,
                // other fields... 
              }]
});
```

One concern is that, if there are many favorited users could make the Post collection too large. Make sure no more the collection limit, **16 megabytes**.

Whatever, the data schema should meet your data, and facilitate to query it.

Comment: u did second populate - Post.populate(user.posts, .. this doesn't helped the result is []

Comment: @Dizzy, per your document, `favorited: []` is empty, so there is no user to populate...

Comment: not it is not, please note favorited: [Object], on 'post 1'

Comment: @Dizzy, please use `require('util').inspect(ret, { showHidden: true, depth: null }` to show the content of `[Object]` to check whether this result is populated or not?

Comment: @Dizzy, all the result is `[]`? if so, it is weird, I test some data in my local, it works well...

Comment: @Dizzy, per the same issue posted in mongoose, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1381,

Comment: Eventually @zangw you're right. So no as there are no joins in Mongoose we are going to use populate. First step is to $elemMatch: {favorited: user.id} so favorited array will be narrowed to 1 element if favorited and empty if not. Then we declare a virtual bool property and removing this property during toJSON() transform.

Comment: @Dizzy do you have an example of what was your final solution for this? I'm facing a similar problem.